# MSWinsock.Winsock event handling in VisualBasic

Tags: events, excel, winsock, vba

I'm trying to handle Winsock_Connect event (Actually I need it in Excel macro) using the following code:

```
Dim Winsock1 As Winsock 'Object type definition

Sub Init()
    Set Winsock1 = CreateObject("MSWinsock.Winsock") 'Object initialization
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "MyHost"
    Winsock1.RemotePort = "22"
    Winsock1.Connect

    Do While (Winsock1.State <> sckConnected)
        Sleep 200
    Loop
End Sub

'Callback handler
Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
    MsgBox "Winsock1::Connect"
End Sub
```

But it never goes to Winsock1_Connect subroutine although Winsock1.State is "Connected".
I want to use standard MS library because I don't have administrative rights on my PC and I'm not able to register some custom libraries.
Can anybody tell me, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you stuck using MSWinsock?
[Here](http://www.ostrosoft.com/oswinsck/oswinsck_reference.aspx) is a site/tutorial using a custom winsock object.

Also... You need to declare Winsock1 **WithEvents** within a "Class" module:

```
Private WithEvents Winsock1 As Winsock
```

And finally, make sure you reference the winsock ocx control.
Tools -> References -> Browse -> %SYSEM%\MSWINSCK.OCX

Comment: The link to the 'site/tutorial' seems to be down, likely for good.

Comment: @Nescio I can't seem to find this file anywhere on a W7 64-bit PC.  How can I add the reference?

Comment: It's not clear at all for me, how do we do "You need to declare Winsock1 WithEvents within a "Class" module:".

Answer (score 0):

Documentation about **Winsock Control**: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228119%28v=vs.60%29.aspx 
Example here: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163999/en-us

My short example with event handling in VBscript:

```vbs
Dim sock
Set sock = WScript.CreateObject("MSWinsock.Winsock","sock_")
sock.RemoteHost = "www.yandex.com"
sock.RemotePort = "80"
sock.Connect

Dim received
received = 0

Sub sock_Connect()
    WScript.Echo "[sock] Connection Successful!"
    sock.SendData "GET / HTTP/1.1"& vbCrLf & "Host: " & sock.RemoteHost  & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
End Sub

Sub sock_Close()
    WScript.Echo "[sock] Connection closed!"
End Sub

Sub sock_DataArrival(Byval b)
    Dim data
    sock.GetData data, vbString
    received = received + b
    WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"
    WScript.Echo " Bytes received: " & b  & " ( Total: " & received & " )"
    WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"
    WScript.Echo data
End Sub

'Wait for server close connection
Do While sock.State <> 8
    rem WScript.Echo sock.State
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Output will be:

`cscript /nologo sockhttp.vbs`

```
[sock] Connection Successful!
-------------------------------
 Bytes received: 1376 ( Total: 1376 )
-------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 15:41:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 15:41:36 GMT
...
```