# Telnet (winsock) connection in VBA - class not registered

Tags: vba, ms-access, telnet, winsock

I have GSM gateway that use telnet for sending/recivieng SMS. I'am making a small app in my ms-access for sending sms notifications for my clients. For that I need winsock connection from my client computer -> gsm gateway. It supposed to be easy :)

I can't establish an object. I'm receiving run-time error -2147221164(80040154) - Class not registered. Error is indicated in "Set winsock = ..." line. I have added reference MS Winsock Control 6.0 (SP6) - MSWINSCK.OCX. I have a feeling this is a problem with reference, but I don't have any idea how to correct it (code below is simplified) :( .

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Winsock1 As Winsock

Sub Start_Telnet_Session()

Dim Data As String
Dim Winsock1

Set Winsock1 = New MSWinsockLib.Winsock

Winsock1.RemoteHost = "192.168.1.1"
Winsock1.RemotePort = "23"
Winsock1.connect
   
Do Until Winsock1.State = 7
    DoEvents
    If Winsock1.State = sckError Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
Winsock1.SendData "user" & vbCrLf
Winsock1.SendData "pass" & vbCrLf
Dim I As Integer
I = 5
While TelnetCommands <> ""
    Winsock1.SendData "TelnetCommands" & vbCrLf
    Winsock1.GetData Data
    Data = VBA.Replace(Data, vbLf, "")
    Data = VBA.Replace(Data, vbCr, vbNewLine)
    MsgBox Data
    I = I + 1
Wend
Winsock1.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSWinsock.Winsock event handling in VisualBasic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125921/mswinsock-winsock-event-handling-in-visualbasic)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was trying to implement the code in the second answer (befzz) but first of all I don't understand it (probably VBScript - not VBA), and second after implementing it I received error variable not defined in "Set sock = WScript (...)" line.